# R iGraph Error "non-numeric argument to binary operator" while adding an edge

Tags: r, igraph

I am trying to generate a graph using iGraph library in R

**Script**

```
library("igraph")

#set the size of the graph
graphSize = 20

g <- graph.empty(graphSize, dir =FALSE)

V(g)$color <- c("grey")

#Number of steps to create the graph
steps <- 10

#create a vector where
x <- sample(1:graphSize, steps, replace=T)
print("Node To Connect")
print (x)

#coin tossing with Bias 
toss <- function(){
    y <- sample(0:1, size = 1, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.1,0.9))   
    #print (y)
}

#Connect a random vertice with preselected random vertice if toss result is 1
connect <- function( graph , vertice, graphSize ) {
    tossResult <- toss()
    if ( tossResult == 1 ){
        nodeToConnect <- sample(1:graphSize, 1 , replace=T)
        print(nodeToConnect)
        graph <- graph + edge(vertice, nodeToConnect)
    }
}

#for each random nodes chosen previously in x vector an edge with another random verice is created
for (i in seq_along(x) ){
    g <- connect(g, x[i], graphSize)
}
```

After sourcing the codes into R, sometimes it is giving me the desired graph and sometimes showing the following error:

**Error**

```
Error in graph + edge(vertice, nodeToConnect) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Interestingly after showing the error the graph object "g" becomes null. I am newbie to R. Any suggestion for improving the function is welcome too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `connect` function sometimes returns the graph, sometimes not. Note that in R a function returns the value of the last expression of the function. So sometimes you return `tossresult`, sometimes `graph`.

The fix is:

```
connect <- function( graph , vertice, graphSize ) {
    tossResult <- toss()
    if ( tossResult == 1 ){
        nodeToConnect <- sample(1:graphSize, 1 , replace=T)
        print(nodeToConnect)
        graph <- graph + edge(vertice, nodeToConnect)
    }
    graph
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach creates an empty graph with 20 vertices, then adds edges at random. Here's a different way to generate this type of graph which essentially creates the edges first (as an adjacency matrix), and then creates the graph at the end.

```
library(igraph)
graphSize <- 20
steps     <- 10
# set.seed(1)               # for reproducible example
x   <- sample(1:graphSize, steps, replace=T)
adj <- matrix(0,nc=graphSize,nr=graphSize)
for (i in x) adj[i,sample(1:graphSize,1,replace=T)]<-sample(0:1,1,p=c(0.1,0.9))
g <- graph.adjacency(adj)   # create the graph
g <- as.undirected(g)       # declare it undirected
plot(g)
```